# When is (*b) false?

Tags: c++

I am just playing around with pointers, and I have a question.

I wrote the following while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 10;
    int *b = &a;

    while(*b){ cout << "true"; break; }

    cout << endl;
    cout << b;

    return 0;
}
```

When will the condition, (*b) be false? If I don't point it to a value, the code simply doesn't compile.

Also, how whould you translate that conditional test to english?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote for no reason? All I did was ask a properly formed question...

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter, *but* I'd expect virtually any decent book on C or C++ to explain what `if (x)` means within the first few chapters (e.g., *The C Programming Language* covers it in  chapter 1, on page 17, though you do have to read between the lines a bit to realize that's what it's saying).

Comment: Or I could just post a properly formed question with a proper code example and *pray* to not be treated rudely...I understand conditionals, I just didn't understand how a pointer could be used as one. Sometimes we don't always see the obvious answer, and we need a little nudge to get us there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code it would only be false if `a` is zero.  It's not, so the condition will never be false.

`*b` dereferences the pointer `b` and evaluates as the pointed-to value. Since `b` points to `a`, it will always be true that `*b == a` (unless you change `b` to point somewhere else).

The English translation of `while (*b)` is "execute the body of this loop as long as the object `b` points to evaluates as true."  An `int` is true when its value is non-zero.

Comment: Awesome, this is very interesting. So if the value that *b points too is null (ascii and unicode value 0), it will still be true?

Comment: @DracoM. `b` is declared as a pointer-to-`int`. It can't point at a value that is null, because null is not in the value domain of `int`. If you change the value of `a` to 0 then the condition will be false, because `*b == a` and 0 is false when evaluated in boolean context.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detailed and helpful explanation, and not just berating me for asking a basic question, which I couldn't find a straight answer for via Google.

Comment: @DracoM. Note that all of this has nothing to do with the pointer `b`. The results would be exactly the same if you used `a` instead of `*b` (you don't need `b` at all). If you want to check whether the pointer `b` itself is non-null, you would write `while(b)` instead of `while(*b)`. In your case, that would *always* be true, regardless of the value of `a`, because `b` points to something (`a`) and is therefore non-null, no matter what the value of `a` is. So that case would actually be about the pointer and not the pointed-to value.

Comment: @DracoM. You can see better what is going on, if you also output `cout << *b`. You would see that it is exactly the value of `a`. Your statement `cout << b` outputs the (non-null) memory address stored in the pointer `b`, i.e. the address of `a`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I know this is a basic question, but this is all very helpful. I am used to higher level languages like Java an Ruby, where pointers are mostly abstracted away.

Answer (score 0):

Condition in the statement

```
while(*b){ cout << "true"; break; }
```

can be translated in English the following way

```
while(*b not_eq 0 ){ cout << "true"; break; }
```

where `not_eq` corresponds to English words `not equal`.:) This statement with `not_eq` shall be compiled if you have a modern compiler.

Take into account that in this particular case `*b` is equal to `10`, because `b` points to `a`

You could write the loop the following way

```
while ( *b not_eq 0 ){ cout << "true"; b = 0; }
```

that is without the break statement. The effect would be the same.

According to the C++ Standard

4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true.